# .NET SpeechSynthesizer throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, speechsynthesizer

I can't seem to find any solutions to my problem anywhere.

I am trying to use SpeechSynthesizer in my application but anything that I try (including code from the Microsoft documentation) but nothing seems to work. The code that I am using is:

```
using (SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer())
{
    // Configure the audio output.   
    synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    // Speak a string synchronously.  
    synth.Speak("test");
}
```

I am using the following namespaces

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using Process = System.Diagnostics.Process;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
```

I got the code from the Microsoft .NET documentation here:
[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speak?view=netframework-4.8)

The code throws a System.NullReferenceException at `synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();` and when I comment the line out it throws it here too `synth.Speak("test");`

The stack trace says that it is from the System.Speech dll or at least I think it is anyway; I'm not sure. A link to the stack trace is:

```
   at System.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.HKEYfromRegKey(RegistryKey regKey)
   at System.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.RootHKEYFromRegPath(String rootPath)
   at System.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.Open(String registryPath, Boolean fCreateIfNotExist)
   at System.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.ObjectTokenCategory.Create(String sCategoryId)
   at System.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.SAPICategories.DefaultDeviceOut()
   at System.Speech.Internal.Synthesis.VoiceSynthesis..ctor(WeakReference speechSynthesizer)
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_VoiceSynthesizer()
   at System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer.get_Voice()
   at SampleSynthesis.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Sonic\Desktop\test\Program.cs:line 26
```

There appear to be other questions that are related to this, and so my question does not appear to be a simple duplicate of other NRE related questions. Here are some similar questions that may help provide an answer:

- [Nullreference in microsoft.speech](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253112/nullreference-in-microsoft-speech-when-getting-installed-recognizers-even-though)...
- [NullReferenceException with SpeechSynthesizer in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61149644/nullreferenceexception-with-speechsynthesizer-in-unity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Click on the magnifying glass for StackTrace and post the text instead. You likely didn't setup something, which causes the methods on `synth` to misbehave.

Comment: Sorry I completely forgot to provide a stacktrace. It may have helped with a solution. I have edited the question with the stacktrace. However, it did help me understand what I was up against I still haven't found a solution. (for the comment by Dour High Arch)

Comment: @Kit I have edited the post with the magnifying glass version of the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm loathe to post an answer, but it appears you're in "good company" as far as this issue.  Searching **HKEYfromRegKey** yields several NRE and synthesizer related results. It may be as simple as missing an expected key in the Windows registry.

Comment: This question is not simply an NRE duplicate, and shouldn't be closed, as there are at least two SO questions (unresolved) that are similar. That means a real solution would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while but I found an answer. I didn't have System.Speech installed in the Manage NuGet Packages section. I just added the DLL from `Add a project reference` but it was not installed so it was throwing the NullReferenceException. For anyone else who has this problem you must install the NuGet package by going to `Project > Manage NuGet Packages > Browse` then search `System.Speech` in the search bar, click on the package with the .NET icon and press Install.

Also thanks for everyone who tried to help :)